# Exchange 2013/2016 Queue Viewer and corresponding log location

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-2016

Dear all i am having a number of mail flow issues and checking on the the queue from powershell `Get-Queue` I get the the following:

```
Identity       DeliveryType          Status MessageCount Velocity RiskLevel OutboundIPPool NextHopDomain
--------       ------------          ------ ------------ -------- --------- -------------- -------------
ex1\285        DnsConnectorDelivery  Retry  2            0        Normal    0              domain1.com
ex1\351        SmtpDeliveryToMailbox Ready  0            0        Normal    0              mailbox 1
ex1\352        DnsConnectorDelivery  Ready  0            0        Normal    0              domain2.com
ex1\452        DnsConnectorDelivery  Ready  0            0        Normal    0              domain3.com
ex1\578        DnsConnectorDelivery  Active 1            0        Normal    0              domain4.com
ex1\1818       DnsConnectorDelivery  Retry  1            0        Normal    0              domain5.com
ex1\1819       DnsConnectorDelivery  Retry  1            0        Normal    0              domain6.com
ex1\Submission Undefined             Ready  0            0        Normal    0              Submission
```

I enabled verbose logging for the the SMTP connector, but when i look in the log file location i am unable to find any further info as to the issue (i see messages that are sending OK and nothing about the failed message or any retries).

Checking Queue Viewer it is giving further details as below, socket closed by remote host, which gives further info.

Any idea where the corresponding logs for the Queue Viewer would be for outbound SMTP that would give the same level of detail and allow me to search with Powershell?

[image: QueueViewer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-QueueDigest is the command that you want. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998047(v=exchg.160).aspx